# Apache Airflow/Composer : how to connect to https using http connector with untrusted certificate

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am looking to connect to an external API through HTTPS with Airflow.

To do that, I configure my http Airflow connector regarding the documentation.

I setted my host with my url : myurl.com
Then i setted the schema value to 'https' as expected in the documentation.

And because I need a certificate, according to the http_hook documentation ([airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/hooks/http_hook.html#HttpHook.run_and_check)) I added extra option : {"cert":"/home/airflow/gcs/data/mycertificate.pem"}

I am using Composer on the Google Cloud Platform, so I putted my certificate in the corresponding google cloud storage bucket ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage))

I am not sure about my configuration but when I try to use the SimpleHttpOperator

> ```
> get_token = SimpleHttpOperator(
>     task_id='get_access_token',
>     method='POST',
>     headers={
>         "Authorization": "Basic mytooken=="},
>     endpoint='/SASLogon/oauth/token',
>     http_conn_id='myconnid',
>     trigger_rule="all_done",
>     response_filter=lambda response: response.json()['access_token']
> )
> ```
>
> get_token

I have the following error :

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1131)

I am not sure if the error is due to my cert which is not found or due to my self-signed certificate.

Anyway, I am pretty sure I have got to add a configuration somewhere because my certificate is self-signed.

Have you got any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleHttpOperator` is just a simple call to Python's `Requests` library.

**If you are googling this question**, familiarize yourself with this stuff I guess:

- [the python requests library](https://www.nylas.com/blog/use-python-requests-module-rest-apis/)
- [Airflow HttpHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/http/hooks/http.html#HttpHook.conn_name_attr)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late, anyway I resolved the same issue like that:

```
get_token = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='get_access_token',
    method='POST',
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Basic mytooken=="},
    endpoint='/SASLogon/oauth/token',
    http_conn_id='myconnid',
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    response_filter=lambda response: response.json()['access_token'],
    extra_options={"verify":"/home/airflow/gcs/data/<you_pem>.pem"}
)
```

Anyway best way to solve that for me should be to have a *complete Airflow connection*, so *installing the pem inside the Airflow Webserver* and thus **eliminating the need to specify extra_options at task level**.

**NOTE:** In my case the pem was all the certificate chain, no just the final certificate.